# Jitsi Video bridge component, prosody, loadbalancing

Tags: video-streaming, jitsi

I’m setting up an auto-scalled loadbalanced environment using jitsi on AWS, it will autoscale jitsi-videobridge instances connecting them to prosody.

I’ve followed this guide:
https://github.com/jitsi/jicofo/blob/master/doc/load_balancing.md

am I supposed to create separate components for each individual jitsi-videobridge instance at prosody ?
Or am I missing something at the configuration ?
If I understand this correctly, you have separate nodes of jitsi-videobridge talking to XMPP server and sending statistics via PUBSUB where Jicofo does the logic behind loadbalancing of these jitsi-videobridges.

Thanks a lot !

When I try to connect the second jitsi-videobridge into prosody I’m getting this error:

Output from JVB:

```
JVB 2017-05-17 15:38:46.808 SEVERE: [33] org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain.call().278 conflict, host: IP, port:5347
org.xmpp.component.ComponentException: conflict
        at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponent.connect(ExternalComponent.java:219)
        at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponentManager.addComponent(ExternalComponentManager.java:221)
        at org.jivesoftware.whack.ExternalComponentManager.addComponent(ExternalComponentManager.java:201)
        at org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain$3.call(ComponentMain.java:270)
        at org.jitsi.meet.ComponentMain$3.call(ComponentMain.java:255)
        at org.jitsi.retry.RetryStrategy$TaskRunner.run(RetryStrategy.java:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Output from PROSODY:

```
mod_component   info    Disconnecting component, <stream:error> is: <stream:error><conflict xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'>Component already connected</text></stream:error>
May 17 15:39:16 jcp20c3ae0      info    component disconnected: jitsi-videobridge.domainname.com (false)
```

The config file from PROSODY:

```
VirtualHost "pubsub.domainname"
    admins= {  "jitsi-videobridge.domainname” }
    modules_enabled = {
        "pubsub";
    }

VirtualHost "domainname"
    authentication = "anonymous"
    modules_enabled = {
        "bosh";
    }
    c2s_require_encryption = false

VirtualHost "auth.domainname"
    authentication = "internal_plain"

admins = { "focus@auth.domainname" }

Component "conference.domainname" "muc"
Component "jitsi-videobridge.domainname"
    component_secret = "password"
Component "focus.domainname"
    component_secret = “password”
```

The config from JVB:

```
# Jitsi Videobridge settings

# sets the XMPP domain (default: none)
JVB_HOSTNAME=domainname.com

# sets the hostname of the XMPP server (default: domain if set, localhost otherwise)
JVB_HOST=IP

# sets the port of the XMPP server (default: 5275)
JVB_PORT=5347

# sets the shared secret used to authenticate to the XMPP server
JVB_SECRET=password
# extra options to pass to the JVB daemon
JVB_OPTS="--apis=xmpp,rest"

# adds java system props that are passed to jvb (default are for home and logging config file)
JAVA_SYS_PROPS="$JVB_EXTRA_JVM_PARAMS -Dnet.java.sip.communicator.SC_HOME_DIR_LOCATION=/etc/jitsi -Dnet.java.sip.communicator.SC_HOME_DIR_NAME=videobridge -Dnet.java.sip.communicator.SC_LOG_DIR_LOCATION=/var/log/jitsi -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/etc/jitsi/videobridge/logging.properties"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon the same problem. For any future visitors do this:

Add the following to your `/etc/jitsi/videobrigde/config`:

```
JVB_OPTS="--subdomain=jvb1"
```

or

```
JVB_OPTS="--subdomain=jvb2"
```

respectively.

Add another component to `/etc/prosody/conf.d/jitsi.example.com.cfg.lua`:

```
Component "jvb1.jitsi.example.com"
    component_secret = "password"
Component "jvb2.jitsi.example.com"
    component_secret = "password"
```